# Solving $y'' - 2y' + y = \delta(t-2)$ for y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 0 by using Laplace Transforms. Need help finishing the problem.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution, dirac-delta

So I'm working on this question and I've taken the Laplcace transforms for everything and separated it as $Y(s) = F(s)G(s)$, and then I've put it into the convolution equation to get $y(t)$. My problem is, I don't understand how to fully/properly integrate this when I have the $\delta(T-2)$ inside the integral. Can anyone explain what to do? I'm adding a picture of what I have until now that I am *sure* is correct so that there's somewhat of an explanation of my train of thought? (the u and v' at the bottom were if I was going to solve with integration by parts, which I also am not sure of how to use here).
But yeah, please help and tell me where I'm going wrong...

[image: my working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'' - 2y' + y = \delta(t-2)$$
$$\implies Y(s)=\dfrac {e^{-2s}}{(s-1)^2}$$
The inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac 1 {(s-1)^2}$ is simply $e^tt$ then apply the formula 27:
$$L^{-1} (e^{-cs}F(s))=u(t-c) f(t-c)$$
You should get :
$$y(t)=u(t-2)e^{t-2}(t-2)$$

Comment: Hi, can you explain why you used the u (I'm assuming heaviside) function, instead of the dirac-delta function?

Comment: Yes I used Heaviside function @Applesauce44   I applied formula 25 or  27  here in this Laplace table https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx

Comment: would we not need to convolve the laplace transforms of $e^{-2s}$ and $\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}$ with each other? And also, why would we not just use formula 26? I'm sorry for all these questions but it would really help if you could clarify the reasons for doing what you did...

Comment: Formula 27 is the best for your differential equation @Applesauce44

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform of $1/(s-1)^2$ is easy to find then apply formula 27 .....@Applesauce44

Comment: I added some lines hope it's more clear @Applesauce44

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with what you did.
\begin{align*}
y(t) & = \int_0^t \delta(T-2) (t-T)e^{t-T} \ dT \\
& = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t < 2 \\
(t-2)e^{t-2} & \text{if } t \ge 2,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where we made use of the sifting property of the delta function
$$ \int_a^b \delta(x-x_0) f(x) \ dx = \begin{cases}
f(x_0) & \text{if } a < x_0 < b \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$